# How can I quit Firefox via command line in Windows without forcing it?

Tags: windows, command-line, firefox

I want to quit Firefox from the command line, without "forcing" it. I just want to cause the same as clicking Quit in the menu in Firefox would.

Seems I need to call "goQuitApplication" somehow, based on the following.

I tried making a xul file and running that, but I got an error in it. I tried running the file from this [Mozillazine post](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2275175), but Firefox said in the console that "TypeError: Components.classes is undefined".

The following is the code of that xul file:

```
Remote XUL Manager by Jorge Villalobos
https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/235281/

Domains with remote XUL permission: <Local files>

Loads the specified chrome:
firefox -chrome example.xul

-->

<window onload="load()"
        xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

  <script type="application/javascript">
  <![CDATA[

    function load() {
      var wm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].
        getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
      var win = wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
      win.setTimeout("goQuitApplication()", 250);
      window.close();
    }

  ]]>
  </script>

</window>
```

I've tried simply calling "goQuitApplication" inside the load function, (which seemingly works if called inside the browser console) but then I got the error "ReferenceError: goQuitApplication is not defined".

Does anyone know of a good way to quit Firefox from the command line, without force killing the process or closing individual windows?

Comment: Have you checked whether [Taskkill](http://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html) or its Powershell equivalent, [Stop-Process](http://ss64.com/ps/stop-process.html), were suited for your needs?

Comment: when i call TASKKILL /im firefox.exe, firefox seems to act as if i had closed the most recently used firefox window (asking me if i really want to close <# of tabs open in that window>), instead of just quitting.

Comment: That's expected behavior of a default Firefox installation. You can always disable that confirmation, in the Options > Tabs - "Warn me when closing multiple tabs".

Comment: yes, i realize that. the problem is that i use multiple windows, and this only closes one of them. also, the tabs are then considered "closed", so they wont come back next time you open firefox.

Comment: Asking that question is what Firefox likes to do.  If you don't want Firefox to ask that question, then you're trying to force Firefox to close without performing its standard behavior.  However, in this SuperUser.com question, you specifically said "without forcing".  So you need to make up your mind: do you want to force, or not?

Comment: firefox asks nothing if you click quit in the menu, and it closes all the windows, and brings the whole session back when you reopen firefox. that is the behavior i was trying to trigger from the command line, somehow. it only asks that question when you actually close a window that has multiple tabs in it; i wasnt trying to close anything at all, just quit firefox (which of course, also closes all the windows, but they are still part of the session). what i meant by not forcing it was that i didnt want to just kill the process from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually ran into this question yesterday. I was looking for the answer myself. Not a big deal if you only have one windows open (a simple taskkill line without the /f so that the browser can close cleanly) but as soon as you have two windows or more, it becomes alot more complicate because the taskkill command will only shot one window at a time (effective loosing the tabs of the window unless it's the last one to be closed).

I ended up writing a combo of cmd/vbs scripts to close firefox cleanly. Scripts will detect if Master Password prompt is open and close it (avoid the prompt from interfering with FFQuit script), FFQuit script will then activate FF and send an Alt-F key stroke to open file menu and an X to exit firefox.

There you have it a quick and clean exit, all windows come back upon restart. There's the option to restart FF as well (just uncoment the relevant section):

**Part 1: the encapsulating cmd script: quitFF.cmd**

> ```
> set FFexec=%programfiles(x86)%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
> set ERRORLEVEL=
>
> :: Check if that annoying Master Password prompt is open and close it
> tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Password Required" 2>NUL | find /I /N firefox.exe">NUL
> IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" MPWDclose.vbs
>
> FFQuit.vbs
>
> ::Optional Restart Firefox - ping is just a sneaky way of getting sleep functionality
> ::Uncomment REM to activate
> REM ping 1.0.0.0 -n 1 -w 2000 > nul
> REM start ""  "%FFexec%" & exit
> ```

**Part 2: MPWDclose.vbs**

> ```
> Set MPWDclose = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
>
> WScript.Sleep 250
> MPWDclose.AppActivate("Password Required")
> WScript.Sleep 250
> MPWDclose.Sendkeys "{ESC}"
> WScript.Sleep 50
> WScript.Quit
> ```

**Part 3: FFQuit.vbs**

> ```
> Set FFquit = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
> WScript.Sleep 250
> FFquit.AppActivate("- Mozilla Firefox")
> WScript.Sleep 250
> FFquit.Sendkeys "%F"
> WScript.Sleep 100 
> FFquit.Sendkeys "x"
> WScript.Quit
> ```

Comment: I know it's been a couple of years, but thanks for this. I don't have Master Password enabled, so all I actually needed was that VBS file. But it works beautifully. Saved me a bunch of headache.

Comment: It's pretty neat that something I put up a few years ago is helping someone today. Thanks for the feedback. :)

Comment: Gotta love the timelessness of the interwebs.

Comment: I just configure my browsers to save and restore all windows and tabs and terminate cleanly instead of showing dialog boxes that block OS requests to end the process gracefully.